# Difference between Rails 2.3 and Rails 3.2 'weeks' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've noticed some different behaviour between Rails 2 and Rails 3 when it comes to ActiveSupport date handling.

When I run the following code in a Rails 2.3 application it runs as I expect and outputs the dates one week at a time.

```
>> first = Date.today
=> Fri, 23 Mar 2012
>> last = Date.today + 2.months
=> Wed, 23 May 2012
>> first.step(last, 1.week) { |date| puts date }
2012-03-23
2012-03-30
2012-04-06
2012-04-13
2012-04-20
2012-04-27
2012-05-04
2012-05-11
2012-05-18
```

When I try the same code within a Rails 3 application I get the following.

```
>> first = Date.today
=> Fri, 23 Mar 2012
>> last = Date.today + 2.months
=> Wed, 23 May 2012
>> first.step(last, 1.week) { |date| puts date }
Mar 23, 2012
TypeError: expected numeric
```

The problems seems to be with how Rails 3 is now handling the .weeks method, Rails 2 outputs the following

```
>> 1.week
=> 7 days
```

Where Rails 3 outputs

```
>> 1.week
=> 604800
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here and how I can neatly iterate over a date range one week at a time in Rails 3.

Comment: That works fine for me in Rails 3.2.

Comment: I'm running Rails 3.2.1, did you test it with that same version?

Comment: I checked with 3.2.1 in the Rails console. I can get 604800 out of `1.week` if I force it to be a number with something like `1.week.to_i`.

Answer (score 1):

No idea why it doesn't work, but this seems to:

```
(Date.today..(Date.today + 30)).step(7)
```

Comment: Putting in a 7 works for me as well but it just doesn't have the same meaning or read as well as 1.week

Comment: You're right, it's much less clear. Factor it out into a well named method?